# Working with Raspberry Pi 3 + Windows 10 IoT Core + DHT22

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

Wondering if there is any sample wiring and code for Raspberry Pi 3  + Windows 10 IoT Core + DHT22 ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
static class DHT22
{
    private const int intGpioData = 18;
    private static GpioPin gpioData;

    public static void Start()
    {
        //Init GPIO And Capture Data Every 2000ms
        GpioController gpioController = GpioController.GetDefault();
        gpioData = gpioController.OpenPin(intGpioData);
        gpioData.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp);
        new Timer(new TimerCallback((obj) => { GetData(); }), null, 2000, 2000);
    }

    private static void GetData()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[40];
        gpioData.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        gpioData.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        Task.Delay(1).Wait();
        gpioData.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp);

        //Record Data
        while (gpioData.Read() == GpioPinValue.High) ;
        while (gpioData.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low) ;
        while (gpioData.Read() == GpioPinValue.High) ;
        byte low;
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            low = 0;
            data[i] = 0;
            while (gpioData.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low && low <= byte.MaxValue) 
                   low++;
            while (gpioData.Read() == GpioPinValue.High && data[i] <= byte.MaxValue) 
                   data[i]++;
        }

        //Analyze Data
        byte humiH = 0;
        byte humiL = 0;
        byte tempH = 0;
        byte tempL = 0;
        byte sum = 0;
        for (short i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            byte bit = data[7 - i] >= 11 ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
            humiH += (byte)(bit << i);
        }
        for (short i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            byte bit = data[15 - i] >= 11 ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
            humiL += (byte)(bit << i);
        }
        for (short i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            byte bit = data[23 - i] >= 11 ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
            tempH += (byte)(bit << i);
        }
        for (short i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            byte bit = data[31 - i] >= 11 ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
            tempL += (byte)(bit << i);
        }
        for (short i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            byte bit = data[39 - i] >= 11 ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
            sum += (byte)(bit << i);
        }

        //Verify Data
        if ((byte)(humiH + humiL + tempH + tempL) == sum)
        {
            double humidity = (double)(humiH * 256 + humiL) / 10;
            double temperature = (double)(tempH * 256 + tempL) / 10;
            Debug.WriteLine(humidity + "% " + temperature + "°C");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the tutorials tab it will show you some sample code and wiring for lighting an LED.
I hope this answered your question.

CodeMaster5678

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an SO answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, here is an example.
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/GpioOneWire

Also, if you want to stick to C#, this does work. I used this today with 2 dht11 sensors.

This is the github link:
https://github.com/porrey/Dht

Nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dht/

If you are comfortable with C++, then use that. If not I recommend the Nuget package, only because I verified that it works today. The dht11 sensors seem to have a lot of variance. I have a 3 degree different on two sensors.